Azure Databricks
When I try to create cluster in Azure databricks getting the following error. Why?
Azure Quota Exceeded Exception:
Error code: QuotaExceeded, error message: Operation could not be completed as it results in exceeding approved standardDADSv5Family Cores quota. Additional details - Deployment Model: Resource Manager, Location: CentralIndia, Current Limit: 0, Current Usage: 0, Additional Required: 8, (Minimum) New Limit Required: 8.
I was trying to create create compute (cluster) in Azure Databricks and it keeps on failing.

You are trying to create a cluster using VMs from the DADSv5Family. But your subscription+region quota limit for the DADSv5Family is set to 0.
You need to either select a VM from a family for which you have sufficient quota available or request an increase in the quota for that VM family type.
To check the usage and quota :

Select Subscription
Under Settings
Usage+quotas
Use filter to select tier and region
Check usage and quota for total regional CPUs
Check the usage and quota for the specific family type CPU.

You can raise a request via this link.
You can find more information on this error here.
